# How to use matplotlib save multiple plots to a file in loop

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

```
x = [1 2 5 6 3 .....]
n = len(x)//34
i = 0
while i < n*34:
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
    axs[0].plot(x[i:34+i],y[i:34+i],x_l[i:34+i],y_l[i:34+i]) #knee
    axs[1].plot(x_a[i:34+i],y_a[i:34+i],color = 'red') #ank
    axs[1].plot(x_l_a[i:34+i],y_l_a[i:34+i],color = 'green')
    axs[0].axis('off')
    axs[1].axis('off')
    plt.savefig('test')
    i = i + 17
```

The code above will only save the last plot in my file, but I would like to generate and save the multiple plots for different values of `i`.

Comment: `plt.savefig('test' + str(i))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are overwriting the same `"test"` file on every iteration; as such, when your program completes, you are left with only the last figure saved to disk. If you want to save multiple files, you need to use a different filename on every iteration in your call to `savefig`.

For example, you may use the iteration variable `i` and change your call to:

```
plt.savefig("test{}".format(i))
```